# Error in NewRelic log file "warning: dstat(/dev/vzfs) failed - desk metrics not reported this cycle"

Tags: php, newrelic

I'm getting an error in my `nrsysmond.log` file like this:

```
warning: dstat(/dev/vzfs) failed - desk metrics not reported this cycle
```

I've set the php.ini file's `newrelic.loglevel` to `verbosedebug`, `warning`, and `debug` but get the same error.

Does anybody know what would cause this? NewRelic still hasn't been able to collect any data from my application yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely contact New Relic support. Cool that we're collecting "desk" metrics in addition to "disk" metrics. Our team will need to improve our spelling I guess.

Comment: Hah. I have been (trying) to talk to support but I will admit that replies are not quick. ;) I left a message or two on my support ticket that should help them get a solution but was hoping to get it fixed over the weekend. Oh well! :)

Comment: Just found out that the error has to do with server monitoring and not application monitoring and only applies to VPS systems. They're working on a fix but don't have an ETA. :(

Comment: Are you able to get application data reporting yet? Server data?

Comment: @rkb No (for application data reporting), unfortunately they say it is my fault and that I didn't edit the correct php.ini file, although I know I did! Oh well, maybe this is not meant to work nicely on VPS's. :) On the other hand, server data is reporting just fine.

Comment: If it's not working for you, I'd push back on support. Sorry you didn't get a better response.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I've just installed New Relic and have the same error showing up. Apart from that, Server and App monitoring are working just fine...

Comment: Just an update: Considering the age of this post I went ahead and contacted New Relic support about it again. Here is the reponse: Unfortunately we still do not have support for these types of file systems or containers such as OpenVZ. This is on our roadmap but unfortunately I don't have have a timeline to provide you with.

Comment: Looks like I can look forward to getting disk metrics on my OpenVZ VPS "somewhen". I thought I'd set something up wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you run cloudlinux check this out and do as it says:

http://docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?hybrid_kernel.html

Newrelic user cant read the /pro/"pid" directories due to cloudlinux kernel.